# Why I could not do E step at the middle of a Gremlin query?

Tags: graph, gremlin, tinkerpop

I notice that I could not have an E step at the middle of a Gremlin query. Is there a reason behind it, or just the feature is missing?

```
g.V().....E()...
```

Basically, I have an index on an edge property and can do like this to add an edge if it does not exist in one transaction:

```
g.E().has('edgeId', 1).fold().coalesce(__.unfold(), __.addE('link').from(__.V(id1)).to(__.V(id2))
```

But I could not chain the traversal to add multiple edges as a batch. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That feature became available in 3.7.0 ([javadoc](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/current/full/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/process/traversal/dsl/graph/GraphTraversal.html#E(java.lang.Object...))). You can now use `E()` as a start step or use it mid-traversal.